# Is "aging" an adjective?

Tags: verbs, adjectives

In the phrase `the aging woman` is `aging` an adjective or a verb used as an adjective?

Comment: I think you're better off saying that *aging* is a verb (it's a participle) that's used as a noun modifier.  It's different from an adjective like *old* because we can compare adjectives -- *the older woman* -- but not verbs.  We don't say "the aginger woman".

Comment: @deadrat But you could use *more ageing*. *This stage make-up has a more ageing effect, that that which you used previously.*

Comment: It functions as if it were an adjective, but whether it is or not depends on your religion.

Comment: I agree with deadrat. In “the aging woman”, "aging" is a verb functioning as an attributive modifier. It doesn’t have the distinctive properties of adjectives, so it can’t belong in that class. For example, it can’t be modified by “very” (* "very aging”) , and it can’t occur as complement to complex-intransitive verbs (* “It became quite aging”) or complex-transitive verbs like “find” (* ”I found it quite aging”).

Comment: @ ws2 isn't _more_ modifying (aging effect) here, not aging? And since an aging effect is a continuous effect, I'd say greater. The make-up has a greater aging effect.

Comment: There are plenty of adjectives that do not allow comparison. A unique situation is no less or more unique than any other unique situation.  Unique is unique, that's all there is. "Absolute" is another example. Also, unanimous, universal, perpetual, and so on.

Comment: @surlawda And it can't function as complement to complex-intransitive or complex transitive verbs. Adjective is a category label, not a function label. It's vital to distinguish the two.

Comment: Adjectives define nouns. They have no relationship to verbs of any kind.

Comment: Nouns can be modified by several word classes like AdjPs, DPs, nominals and VPs (verbs). Aging belongs to the latter class.

Answer (score 2):

I would see ageing as an adjective (in form of a present participle). And OALD also says it can be used as adjective (only attributive before a noun). But ageing
can also be a noun meaning the process of growing old. But in your example the noun doesn't fit. 
The spelling can also be aging (AmE, BrE).

http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/ageing_2

Answer (score 2):

This is a distinction without a difference. Anything that is properly "used as an adjective" is an adjective. Participles, which may serve as adjectives or nouns, are a type of verbal. Verbals also include gerunds, which function as nouns, and infinitives, which can function as nouns, adjectives, or adverbs. In no case do verbals function as verbs. In your sentence, the participle "aging" is an adjective, because it describes a noun: the black chair, the fast runner, an aging woman. Adjectives describe nouns by answering one of three questions: What kind is it? How many are there? Which one is it? So, which woman? The aging woman.

Comment: No, it's not an adjective; it's a verb functioning as a modifier. It doesn’t have the distinctive properties of adjectives, so it can’t belong in that class. For example, it can’t be modified by “very” (* "very aging”) , and it can’t occur as complement to complex-intransitive verbs (* “It became quite aging”) or complex-transitive verbs like “find” (* ”I found it quite aging”). To call "aging" an adjective would completely mess up the definition of 'adjective'. That's why it's called a modifier', whilst retaining its category status of verb.

Comment: Yes, it is an adjective. There are plenty of adjectives that do not allow comparison. A unique situation is no less or more unique than any other unique situation. Unique is unique, that's all there is. "Absolute" is another example. Also, unanimous, universal, perpetual, and so on.

Comment: And it doesn't mess up the definition of "adjective," which is "a word or phrase naming an attribute, added to or grammatically related to a noun to modify or describe it." That word may come in any one of a number of forms.

Comment: So why can't it function as complement to complex-intransitive or complex transitive verbs?

Comment: No, your confusing category and function. Adjective is a word category while  modifier (which is what "aging" is here) is a function.

Comment: Because adjectives define nouns. Verbs have nothing to do with adjectives.

Comment: No, modifiers 'define' nouns. Adjective is just one kind of modifier. Others are DPs, nominals and VPs (verbs). Deadrat had it right in his comment.

Comment: A DP is a determined noun phrase, as in “Mary loved me 'a little bit.' ” This noun phrase includes an adjective (little). An AdjP is an adjective phrase, making it an adjective. A VP is a verb phrase--which certainly may function as an adjective. It seems in every case, you are still talking about adjectives--or "modifier" if you prefer. Another distinction without a difference.

Comment: No, DP means **determinative phrase**; i.e. a phrase headed by a determinative, for example in the NP _Another **two** candidates_, "another two" is a DP headed by the determinative "two" and modifying the noun "candidates". DP contrasts with AdjP (adjective phrase); AdvP (adverb phrase), NP (noun phrase) and VP (verb phrase) all of which can function as modifiers. So in the NP _the aging woman_, "aging" is a VP functioning as modifier of "woman". You are confusing category and function. Categories are noun, verb, adjective, etc. while functions are subject, object, modifier etc.